# Error: package or namespace load failed for "tidyverse" there is no package called "rlang"

Tags: r, tidyverse, rlang

I've been using "tidyverse", "dplyr" ALL DAY, I was going to start with a different project and the suggested code requeste me to install_github("juba/rows") and install.packages("devtools") after failing to instal it I gave up and went back to a previous project. Now I can't use any of the previously used packages (again I've been using all these packages no problem all day today!)
dplyr
tidyverse
ggplot2
devtools
tibble

they all return the same messsage
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'tidyverse' in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =cI[[i]]): there is no package called 'rlang'

I do hope you can help all return the same massage "there is no package called 'rlang'"

Answer (score 1):

Have you updated your r-base?  If you did, please inform the replaced version.  depending on the previous version, the writing format of the namespace and library directory was updated.  Reinstall and configure ALL packages

Comment: Thank you I updated all the packages to the newest version and that seem to have solved the problem. I appreciate your time, many thanks